# Populating a UITableView with multiple sections correctly?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am new to programming for iOS and I'm running into a weird problem that I can't figure out. I am currently trying to populate the table as follows. There is an initial screen where the user selects categories - sports leagues. I populate an array of strings with the names of the leagues, which will then become the headers for the sections of the table. The league names correspond to other arrays, which have each team in that league, but the number of teams in each league differ. These arrays should populate the correct section (i.e. the number of rows per section will not be static as it depends on the leagues the user initially selects).

I currently have something like this in my numberOfRowsInSection function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   if leagues[section] == "NBA" {
       if (!contains(allTeams, nbaTeams[0])) {
            allTeams += nbaTeams
       }
   }
   return nbaTeams.count
.
.
.
}
```

I have multiple clauses like that for each of my teams. I then am attempting to use my "allTeams" array in my cellForIndexPath function but two things are happening that I don't want to happen. Firstly, the allTeams array was not populated in the same order as my leagues array is in, which I found out through some print statements happens in numberOfRowsInSection - for some reason, the section parameters starts at the greatest section number and then goes to 0 and starts counting up...weird. Secondly, the sections get populated in a repetitive manner. That is, the first section and the second section are populated with the same teams (or how however many sections the user wanted), though the number of teams it populates it with is correct (so the return statements in numberOfRowsInSection are correct).

I feel like I'm missing something about these functions that come from the tableViewDataSource protocol. I'm sorry if this was a mouthful, but I thought this would be easier to read through than an entire class. Thanks for any help you can provide! Also, if there's an altogether better approach for this, please let me know!

Comment: Create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. You're right - we wouldn't want to read through your whole class, so you should create a small but complete example program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: When you say "There is an initial screen where the user selects categories" does it mean that once user selects the category you are moving over to next screen?

Comment: Why are you populating the `allTeams` variable in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method? Also, do all your sections have the same number of rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! In cellForRowAtIndexPath, rather than using allTeams to populate the sections, I created a constant with the correct league and just used a couple of if statements since I don't have a ton of leagues:

```
let currentLeague = leagues[indexPath.section]
if currentLeague == "NBA" {
    cell.textLabel?.text = nbaTeams[indexPath.row]
}
```

etc.